# How to exit the while true loop with esc for python

Tags: python

I tried many ways to exit the while true loop, but I can't.
My code looks like this.

```
import time
import cv2
while True:
    print ("Loop working")
    time.sleep(2)
    c = cv2.waitKey(7) % 0x100
    if c == 27 or c == 10:
       break
```

Comment: why are you doing `% 0x100`? can you print the value of c after you press a key?

Answer (score 0):

You are using waitkey wrong, try like this:

```
c = cv2.waitKey(7) & 0xFF
if c == 27 or c == 10:
   break
```

or simpler:

```
if cv2.waitKey(7) & 0xFF in [10, 27]:
   break
```